# Erro ao iniciar Android Studio após update

Tags: java, android-studio, jdk

Olá, eu estava utilizando o Android Studio normalmente até que a IDE me pediu pra atualizar e foi o que eu fiz. Porém depois da atualização recebi o seguinte erro: "**No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.**". Daí eu tentei adicionar a seguinte linha ao aruivo "studio.sh": "**JAVA_HOME = "/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_73/"**. Porém mesmo assim o problema persiste. Alguém sabe o motivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclui o `bin` no endereço da sua `jdk`, a linha abaixo nas suas variáveis de sistemas. Aqui tem um [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/) de como editar as variáveis de sistemas no linux.

```
JAVA_HOME = "/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_73/bin
```

Ou talvez seja questão de permissão, como eu olhei e descobri que o proprietário e o grupo foram desfeitas, então você pode alterar a permissão/propriedade com:

```
chown -R root:root android-studio
```

Depois disso:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/android-studio/bin
```

e execute

```
./studio.sh
```

Aí tente executar novamente o Android Studio.

Comment: Inclui o "bin" e mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho talvez seja a questão de permissão também. Atualizei a resposta

Comment: `root@guilhermeramalho-Vostro-14-5480:/usr/local# chown -R root:root android-studio/
root@guilhermeramalho-Vostro-14-5480:/usr/local# cd android-studio/bin/
root@guilhermeramalho-Vostro-14-5480:/usr/local/android-studio/bin# ./studio.sh
./studio.sh: 35: ./studio.sh: JAVA_HOME: not found

** (zenity:29850): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-V7BwI7xLkj: Conexão recusada
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.`

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho então realmente não existe o JAVA_HOME dentro de suas configurações. Você terá que adiciona-la para poder funcionar.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho dê uma lida neste artigo: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: Nem o arquivo '.bash_profile' tem aqui :(

.         .AndroidStudio2.1      .bashrc  Desktop     .filezilla  .gradle        .local    .mysql             .pki      .thumbnails       .xsession-errors.old
..        AndroidStudioProjects  .cache   .dmrc       .gconf      .ICEauthority  Modelos   .netbeans          .profile  Vídeos
.android  .bash_history          .config  Documentos  .gksu.lock  Imagens        .mozilla  .oracle_jre_usage  Público   .Xauthority
Android   .bash_logout           .dbus    Downloads   .gnome      .java          Música    .pam_environment   .ssr    .xsession-errors

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho qual linux vc usa?

Comment: Uso o Elementary OS. Mas eu tentei criar o arquivo e colocar as linhas do tutorial e funcionou. Valeu mesmo pela paciência cara. Foi certinho agora. Abraço!

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho beleza, se quiser dar os créditos, tamo aqui. Sucesso aí pra você! Abs. Vou editar passando o link para configurar as varíaveis de sistema. Boa Sorte.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho Aí vc pode colocar minha resposta como certa em relação a pergunta. Qualquer coisa, precisar, só da um grito aqui.

Comment: Claro! Tinha esquecido de fazer isso.